# Avoiding phishing warnings when duplicate content is legitimate

Tags: security, google-chrome, phishing

The situation we have is that two sites are running simultaneously in an A/B test with the new site likely to completely replace the old once we have learned what need to from the A/B test.

The subject matter of the site includes content on a page that talks about a bank. This page exists on the old site and has been copied across to the new site so the user can find the info out regardless of the site they are on.

The problem is that Google Chrome has flagged this as a phishing page, i.e. it has noticed the very similar content, noticed the subject matter and, quite reasonably, come to the conclusion that the new page is an attempt to deceive users.

How can we solve this problem so that users of either site do not see a phishing warning?

As a front end dev I have only a small amount of knowledge of server side things, the comment mentions dkim and SPF records, I've tried neither.

Comment: This is interesting. Do you use SPF & DKIM?

Comment: @Dominik: SPF and DKIM are for email; this is about a web page.

Comment: Did Google  specifically tell you it's due to duplicate content, or are you just assuming that? Do you have a link to the page or info from Google Webmaster regarding this issue?

Comment: @Andy, no it was an assumption, but the page was a precise copy, it didn't even sit in the same frame as the site, wasn't CMS driven, it was just it's own, static page copied across ... the HTML as well as the content will have been the same. Unfortnately (well, unfortunately for us as the curious observers, fortunately for the client!) the split test is now over, the initial domain is deleted and the page does not throw the same error anymore

Comment: It might be best to test bank sites internally in that case, or use Google Analytics built in A/B testing functions. I answered below with my own experiences, maybe it'll help someone else. Generally I do not believe Google care about duplicate content - as such. They might penalize it in rankings, but not block it. A Bank-related site, well that might be different of course :)

Comment: @Andy interestingly, it was just the page relating to banking, which was one of three or four that had been subjected to the same development strategy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This answer is based partly on personal experience, and on official Google policies (link included). Other may have different experiences. Hope it helps a little anyway.

At this time, Google will mark a page as "Phishing", even if the actual problem is something else, like a malicious script or a malware executable download. Or at least what Google *thinks* is malicious based on their algorithms. They may also mark either a page or your entire domain as "Phishing" depending on how many total pages they think look suspicious. Mentioning a Bank may in fact trigger something, but I'm speculating on that, only Google really knows. Their policies also change frequently, so keep up-to-date on them  [via this link](https://support.google.com/adwordspolicy/answer/190443?hl=en)

Using [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) (you should sign up), you can see the list of issues, but to clear a blocked site, you need to essentially ask for a review of it (The same place as you can get to if you click on "Advanced > Report an incorrect warning" in the Phishing warning itself).

The process of getting it cleared is painful, and you essentially won't hear back or get even a confirmation email or ticket. So have patience, and try again after a few days. Hopefully this will change in the future.

I highly recommend scanning your site with [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) (Chose url scan), and make 100% sure there really is no malicious script embedded on your pages (If you server was hacked, it could be).